# Ubuntu Server: how do I upgrade from 16.04 to 17.04 to get better hardware support?

Tags: upgrade, kernel

I need hardware support afforded by the newer kernel, so I'm looking to upgrade, but I have only seen instructions relating to desktop editions and need guidance for upgrading Ubuntu Server.

Comment: AFAIK the procedure is the same

Comment: Why do you want to upgrade? 16.04 LTS has long time support (5 years until April 2021), but 17.04 has only 9 months support (from April 2017 until January 2018).

Comment: @sudodus hardware support afforded by the newer kernel

Comment: @AndroidDev can't be the same since the examples I've seen requires me to go to "update software" GUI app and enable an option there

Comment: I see. Well you upgrade stepwise. **Backup!** Make the current system up to date, remove PPAs. Upgrade to 16.10. Make that system up to date. Upgrade to 17.04. `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Comment: @muru and while at first glance it seems a duplicate, things could've changed since then :)

Comment: @mrjayviper then that post should be updated.

Comment: @muru not my concern. perhaps you need to speak to a mod if you think the steps mentioned in that post is very much related to my question :)

Comment: Considering that multiple answers say it isn't supported and so no steps are involved, that's not my concern either. Unless you have any new information about skipping releases being supported, then this post is very much a dupe of that post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to upgrade the release, you can upgrade only kernel by running

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04-edge
```

This will install kernel from 17.04.

To make use of the new kernel, reboot. GRUB2 will automatically picks the latest kernel.